# Fabric in Android Studio says "Make the following changes to your code" then doesn't list anything

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, twitter-fabric

I have a React Native app and am trying to install Fabric with Android Studio. It says "Make the following changes to your code" then doesn't list anything. What am I supposed to do?

[image]

Comment: Those changes might have been already added to your code? Not sure. Could you check your `build.gradle` file and see if you can find the `com.crashlytics.sdk.android` line in the dependency block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use instructions from [Fabric manual setup](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) to check if that changes are already done. And if not, make them yourself.